# Passing a reference argument and returning a reference

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

I've been reading about operator overloading, and have learned that if you return a reference from a function that you can cascade overloaded operators.

My question is this. In order to return a reference, do you need to pass a reference to a function, or will the value do?

e.g. Are both valid?

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream output, string &label);
```

and

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, string &label);
```

Will the first also return a valid reference to the output stream argument passed to the function, or do you need to pass in the output stream object as a reference to return it as a reference?

Comment: If you pass a value, the compiler sends a copy. You then return a reference to the copy, and then the line ends, and the copy gets destroyed... your reference is dangling.

Comment: If you intend to return a reference to something that is passed, that something should be passed as a reference.   In the case of `operator<<()` for streaming to `ostream`s, the `ostream` must be passed by reference.    Passing by value means a reference to a temporary (the argument) is returned, which causes undefined behavioour.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream output, std::string &label);
```

since `std::ostream` does not have a copy constructor.

Even if `std::ostream` had a copy constructor, using the above interface would cause the following problems.

#### Problem 1

Returning a reference to the input argument would be a problem. The object will not be alive after the function returns. Hence, the returned reference would be dangling reference as soon as the function returned. Using the dangling reference would cause undefined behavior.

#### Problem 2

This is hypothetical.

Imagine what would happen if you used:

```
std::ofstream outfile("myoutput.txt");
outfile << "A string.";
```

The call would result in object slicing. You would lose the `std::ofstream`-ness of the object. Where would the output go in that function? It certainly won't go to the file.

---

Stick with

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &output, std::string const& label);
```

**PS** Yes, I did change the type of the second argument to `const&`.

Comment: And I understand why you added keyword const. Thanks for that :)